Violation of Impersonation policy
Received an email from Google Play recently with a Violation of Impersonation policy, due to word on the app icon. Also, the warning appears on the app page. But the console has no description of what is wrong, just "Appeal", a deadline, and a way to look on email.
As per the email, I changed the app icon in the release, beta track, and store listing. The app icon is completely different from the one before. This update is approved.
But the warning does not disappear and still states that I must fix it before 3 January.
Maybe I doing something wrong?
